# Combining multiple tables with same ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to combine several tables. The goal is to have them all on one table in the end, but sorted by ID. **So if I have a matching ID between some of the tables, it unites into one row based on the ID.**

- There are more than two tables (I currently have three: table1, table2, table3 but I plan to add more in the future)
- Some of the tables don't have the same columns or number of columns.
- Some of the tables don't have the same name for the ID column, table1 has "ID" and table2 has it named "identity" and so on...
- I try not to include each of all the available columns from every table in the code, because there's a good amount of columns in each of the available tables and I assume adding and naming each one of them in the query would be tiring. I do however know the column name of the ID in each of the tables.

So the column names for the ID are: "ID(table1),  Identity(table2),  CatalogNum(table3)"

Here's an example,

```
table1: 
**ID**   | Name  | Price | Date | ....
 000212     Rod     200    NULL    etc
          ...... 

table2: 
Descr        | **Identitiy** | amount | ...
Silver rod        000212         3       NULL
               ......

table3: 
Type   | Price | Condition | **CatalogNum** | .....
Metal     NULL      8         000212         etc
Wood      300       1         000313        etc
              .....
```

So end result should look like:

```
 **ID**  |  Name  |  Price  | Date |  Descr      | amount | Type | Condition | .... | ... | .....
  000212    Rod       200     NULL   Silver rod      3      Metal      8       etc    NULL   etc
  000313    NULL      300     NULL    NULL          NULL    Wood       1       NULL   NULL   etc
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want:

```
Select b.*, c.*, d.* From 
(select ID from table1 union select Identitiy from table2 union select ID from table3)a
left join table1 b on a.ID = b.ID
left join table2 c on a.ID = c.Identitiy
left join table3 d on a.ID = d.ID
```

Comment: What is the purpose of "b", "c", "d" here?

Comment: These are alias, instead of typing table1 a ll over you give it an alias like b. So table1.ID becomes a.ID. shorter and easier to read as code

Comment: But in real life, when you know something about the tables, use meaningful aliases, because that makes the code even easier to read. [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no single source for all of the `ID` values that could occur in the various tables, you'll have to build one, and then use that to join to all of the other tables to get the columns you're interested in.

For the purposes here, I pulled back all of the columns in all of the tables, though.

```
WITH IdList AS (
  SELECT 
    ID AS MasterId
  FROM table1
  UNION
  SELECT
    Identitiy
  FROM table2
  UNION
  SELECT
    CatalogNum
  FROM table3
)
SELECT
  i.MasterID,
  t1.*,
  t2.*,
  t3.*
FROM IdList as i
LEFT JOIN table1 as t1 ON t1.ID = i.MasterID
LEFT JOIN table2 as t2 ON t2.Identitiy = i.MasterID
LEFT JOIN table3 as t3 ON t3.CatalogNum = i.MasterID;
```

Result:

```
+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------------+-----------+--------+-------+--------+-----------+------------+
| MasterID |   ID   |  Name  | Price  |  Date  |   Descr    | Identitiy | amount | Type  | Price  | Condition | CatalogNum |
+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------------+-----------+--------+-------+--------+-----------+------------+
|   000212 | 000212 | Rod    | 200    | (null) | Silver rod | 000212    | 3      | Metal | (null) |         8 |     000212 |
|   000313 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null)     | (null)    | (null) | Wood  | 300    |         1 |     000313 |
+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------------+-----------+--------+-------+--------+-----------+------------+
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/541d6/2)

**EDIT:** Your question notes that you want the data in one table, "`, but sorted by ID.`" SQL tables don't work that way. They are, by definition, unordered sets. You impose order on them by using an `ORDER BY` clause in your `SELECT` queries. So there is no effort in my query above to create any kind of "order" at all.

Comment: When I added more "t*" (tables) and actually used the code on my tables, I recieve duplicate rows with the same ID and same result in the columns... any idea why?